# change/substitute two different pattern in only one line

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

i try to change two different pattern in one line from a file.

the file is a /etc/fstab like :

```
/dev/sda1        /               ext4    auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0       1
/dev/sda2        /home           ext4    auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0       2
```

the result must be :

```
/dev/sda1        /               ext4    auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0       1
/dev/mapper/home /home           ext4    auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0       0
```

what i do on the first pattern:

```
sed -i "s/sda2/mapper\/home/" /etc/fstab
```

for the second pattern i have tried :

```
sed -i "s/sda2/mapper\/home/;s/[0-9]$/0/" /etc/fstab
```

but it update all lines :

```
/dev/sda1        /               ext4    auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0       0
/dev/mapper/home /home           ext4    auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0       0
```

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the syntax `address function-list` to apply a set of commands to lines that match a pattern:

```
sed -i "/sda2/{ s/sda2/mapper\/home/
                s/[0-9]$/0/ }" /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /sda2/{sub(/sda2/, "mapper/home", $1); $NF=0} 1' file | column -t
/dev/sda1         /      ext4  auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0  1
/dev/mapper/home  /home  ext4  auto,acl,errors=remount-ro  0  0
```

Use of `column -t` is for formatting only.